# Proofs found by computer

Tags: soft-question, big-list, proofs, automated-theorem-proving

In 1996, a long-standing open problem was solved by a computer; namely, that [Robbins algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins_algebra) and Boolean algebra are the same. The proof was found by an automated theorem prover.

Moreover, the known proof of Four color theorem contains computer-generated components.

The aim of this question is to list proofs that are (completely or partially) found by computer (whether the only known proof or the one discovered for the *first* time).

Comment: Some sporadic finite simple groups (like the [Lyons group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyons_group) were first constructed using a computer, i.e., their existence proof was (partially) computer-generated.

Comment: The question [Is "Exporimental Complexity Theory" being used to solve open problems](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/524/is-experimental-complexity-theory-being-used-to-solve-open-problems/527#527) is related to this one.

Comment: IMHO you need to distinguish more carefully between "found" and "checked". Gonthier et al.'s proof has definitely not been found by a computer.

Comment: nice question but alas nearly equivalent to [where & how did computers help prove a thm](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/82/where-and-how-did-computers-help-prove-a-theorem)

Comment: Also very similar: [Has any previously unknown result been proven by an automated theorem prover?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/181003/37490).

Answer (score 12):

Another famous example is [Hales' proof of Kepler's conjecture](http://www.math.pitt.edu/~thales/papers/A%20Proof%20of%20the%20Kepler%20Conjecture%20%28Annals%29.pdf) which had a very large computer aided component.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_conjecture#Hales.27_proof):

> In August 1998 Hales announced that the proof was complete. At that stage it consisted of 250 pages of notes and 3 gigabytes of computer programs, data and results.

Answer (score 10):

This is more of a meta answer in that it is a list of lists.

1. [The papers of Doron Zeilberger](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/papers1.html). He is a mathematician and his computer is listed at the coauthor Shalosh B. Ekhad on all papers where the computer played a part in deriving the results.
2. [Work of Georges Gonthier](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/g/Gonthier%3aGeorges.html). He engineered a machine-checked proof of the four colour theorem and has been recently been working on the Feit-Thompson theorem. He recently completed the formalisation of the Odd-Order Theorem.
3. [Archive of Formal Proofs](http://afp.sourceforge.net/) contains proofs checked with Isabelle, and includes correctness theorems for algorithms, the Gauss-Jordan theorem, some order theory, category theory, and many more classical results.
4. [Formalizing 100 Theorems](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/100/), contains machine checked proofs of some famous theorems.

Comment: Thanks. I should clarify that my question is not concerned about proofs verified/validated by computers after discovery, nor results where a computer played a part deriving them (of course we all use computers in our research, but eventually end up with a self-contained mathematical proof that we can't say has been "derived" by a computer). I'm looking for conjectures whose proofs were *generated* (fully or in part) by a computer.

Answer (score 6):

One example is the proof of non-existence of a [projective plane of order 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Finite_projective_planes).

See [The Search for a Finite Projective Plane of Order 10](http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Lam305-318.pdf) and [The Non-existence of Finite Projective Planes of Order 10](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.39.8684).